# Tailpiece is leaking

Tags: bathroom, sink

Why does the tail piece have a spout on the side and what causes it to leak? Do I need to replace the whole piece if water is leaking from the spout?  If so, any recommendations on how to get it off? It’s pretty tight.

Comment: Did you intend to post a photo?

Comment: A photo will help.  Do not know of many tailpieces looking like teapots.  A photo will get everyone on the same page as far as words go.

Comment: The tail piece of what?

Comment: Please [Edit] your question and use the 'sun & mountains' button to inset a photo. Make sure that the text cursor is positioned where you want the pic to appear in your question.

Comment: Without a picture, I'm wondering if you're looking at the fixture that is for operating the pop-up drain.  There should be a ball linkage in that "spout""

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking a kitchen sink, it's probably for a dishwasher drain connection.  If you're talking a bathroom sink, it could be for a drain stopper lever.

Answer (score 0):

Lacking pictures at time of writing, normally the applications for "a spout on the side of a tailpiece" are:

1. To connect to a tube/pipe leading to a floor drain, or other trap
   prone to drying out from disuse as a "greywater primer" (in which
   case the "spout" slopes downwards away from the tailpiece.) A portion of the waste (greywater) from the sink flows to the other trap to keep it full.
2. To drain something else into the sink drain. A diswasher drain on a kitchen sink is typical (in which
   case the "spout" slopes downwards towards the tailpiece.)
3. If the "spout" is clearly an add-on, not part of the tailpiece as made, it may be a "saddle drain" typical of under-sink Reverse Osmosis systems, to drain their wastewater.